# Determinant divisibility by 9

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having troubles with this homework problem, I tried expanding the determinant using co factor expansion but that didn't help. I know that for a number to be dividable by 9, the sum of its digits have to be a multiple of $9$. If anyone has an idea of what I may have overlooked I would greatly appreciate it.

The question is as follows:

Prove True or False. Let $a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h$ and $i$ be single digits. If the $3$ digit numbers
$abc, def$ and $ghi$ are divisible by $9$ then the determinant

\begin{vmatrix}
g & e & c \\ 
h & f & a  \\ 
i & d & b \\ 
\end{vmatrix}

is divisible by 9.

EDIT: The question was copied exactly as it appeared in my textbook. From what I understand "$abc$" denotes the number with digits $a$, $b$, and $c$. So, if $a = 1$, $b = 2$, and $c = 3$, then $abc$ means the number $123$, not $6$. I hope it's clear enough now.

Comment: I think you may have made a mistake in your determinant. $a$ does not appear in it anywhere.

Comment: Indeed, error is now fixed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 9\!:\ 0\equiv a\!+\!b\!+\!c \equiv d\!+\!e\!+\!f \equiv g\!+\!h\!+\!i\, \Rightarrow\, $ sum of rows $\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\,$ rows linearly dependent.